# Does Keras ModelCheckpoint save the best model across multiple fitting sessions?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, data-science

If I have a Keras model fitted with the `ModelCheckpoint` callback and fit it in several 'fitting sessions' (i.e. I call `model.fit()` multiple times), will the callback save the best model in the most recent fitting session or the best model out of all fitting sessions?

Thanks.

Comment: Please try adding in some snippets of what you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. I did an experiment with an existing model and data set. I created a  checkpoint callback as shown and used it in model.fit

```
file_path1=r'c:\temp\file1'
mchk=tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint( filepath=file_path1,  monitor="val_loss", verbose=1,
    save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode="auto", save_freq="epoch" )

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=val_data,
                     batch_size= 128, epochs= 5,  verbose= 1, callbacks=[mchk])
```

I saved the weights only and saved only the weights for the epoch with the lowest validation loss. I set verbose=1 in the callback so  I could see the values of the validation loss on each epoch. Next I ran essentially the same code again but I changed
the name of the filepath to file2. Code for that is below

```
file_path2=r'c:\temp\file2'
mchk=tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint( filepath=file_path2,  monitor="val_loss", verbose=1,
    save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True, mode="auto", save_freq="epoch" )

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=val_data,
                     batch_size= 128, epochs= 5,  verbose= 1, callbacks=[mchk])
```

Now model.fit preserves its state at the end of a session so if you run it a second time
it starts from where it left off. However it does not preserve the state of the callback.
So on the second run the callback initializes the validation loss as np.inf so it will
save the weights at the end of the first epoch for sure. If you don't change the name of the file it will over write the file you saved due to the first run. If in the second run the value of the validation loss for which the weights were saved is LOWER than the validation loss of the first run then you wind up with the best saved weights overall. However if in the second run the validation loss is higher than in the first run you end up not saving the OVERALL best weights. So that's how it works for the case where the the callback has save_weights_only=True. I thought it might behave differently if you save the entire model because it may in that case preserve the state of the callback. So I reran the experiment with save_weights_only=False. The results indicate saving the entire model does not save the state of the callback. Now I am using Tensorflow 2.0. The results  may be different for different versions. I would run this experiment on your version and see if it behaves similarly.

Answer (score 1):

It will save the best model in the most recent fitting session

Comment: Not correct, it will only save the model if it's the best over all fitting sessions, as long as you only create the one callback object (outside of the call to `fit`).

Answer (score 0):

It would save the model for the last `fit()` as you are essentially overwriting the same file.

If you wanted to find the best model over `N` iterations you should save them with a prefix `N` in the file name. This way it will save the best model for a particular `fit()` and you can easily compare them later. You could just manually add in the `N` i.e., `1,2,3,N` for each `fit()`.

```
// Example
ModelCheckpoint(
        '/home/jupyter/checkpoint/best_model_{N}.h5',
        monitor="val_loss",
        save_best_only=True,
        save_weights_only=False,
        mode="min")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a checkpoint will only be saved if the performance is better than over **all** calls to `fit`. In other words, if none of your epochs in the latest call to `fit` had better performance than an epoch in a previous call to `fit`, that previous checkpoint won't be overwritten.

There is one proviso: you must remember to create the callback outside of the call to fit. That is, do this:

```
checkpoint_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    "checkpoint.h5", save_best_only=True)

model.fit(..., callbacks=checkpoint_callback)
...
model.fit(..., callbacks=checkpoint_callback)
```

not this:

```
model.fit(..., callbacks=keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
                   "checkpoint.h5", save_best_only=True))
...
model.fit(..., callbacks=keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
                   "checkpoint.h5", save_best_only=True))
```

The checkpoint callback object has a `best` attribute which stores the best monitored value so far (and is initially set to the worst possible value, e.g. `infinity` if lower is good). This is not reset when the object is passed to `fit`. However, if you instantiate a new callback object within the call to `fit`, as in the latter code, naturally `best` will be initialised to the worst possible value, not the best monitored value stored by other callback objects in previous calls to `fit`.